# Why is this element in the center?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $A$ is an abelian group, and that $G$ is a group. Suppose we have a group homomorphism $$f: A \times G \to G.$$ I have seem the claim that this implies that $f(a,1)$ is in the center of $G.$ Why is this true?

Comment: The result is false as you can see in Yanko's example below. However, it is true if you assume $f$ to be surjective.

Comment: @Don What if I assume that $f(a,f(b,g)) = f(ab,g)$ for all $a,b \in A,g \in G?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong.

Suppose we managed to find a group $G$ and a subgroup $H\leq G$. Such that

1. $H$ is abelian
2. $H$ is not a subgroup of the center of $G$.

Then let $f:H\times G\rightarrow G$ be the map $f(h,g) = h$. This is clearly a group homomorphism, however since $H$ is not a subgroup of the center of $G$ we can find $h\in H$ such that $f(h,1)=h$ is not an element in the center.

It is left to find such $H,G$. You can take:

$G=S_3$ and $H = \left<(12)\right>$, then $H$ is cyclic and so abelian. However it does not commute with $(123)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is the statement true if I add the assumption that $f(a,f(b,g))= f(ab,g)$ for all $a,b \in A$ and $g \in G?$

Comment: @inequalitynoob2 I'm not sure. Perhaps you should post another question with this additional assumption?

Comment: Done, thank you.